# Batch script - how to take last column from a text line

Tags: batch-file

i am having a text file that contain line :

```
08-09 15:39:38.236 D/MVSDKTutorialBasicOpenCloseFileLoop(12054): availableMemory = 636
```

i need to get the 636 value , and till far i was using this :

```
for /f "tokens=6-8" %%i in (D:\Roey\Jen2\OpenCloseFileLoop\Results\Logcat\firstline.txt) do set revision=%%i
```

the problem is that somtimes the line has extra space ( 2054) - and it doesnt work ( i am getting =  )  , any way to always get the last column ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *last element* in the line:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do for %%b in (%%a) do set "revision=%%b"
```

Answer (score 2):

choose your delims wisely:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (file.txt) do set revision=%%a
REM remove any spaces:
set revision=%revision: =%
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not know the number of delimited items in advance, you could use the following code snippet, supposing the text file does not contain any global wildcard characters `*` and `?`:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem /* Define constants here: */
set "FILE=D:\Roey\Jen2\OpenCloseFileLoop\Results\Logcat\firstline.txt"
set "DELIM= " & rem // (define a single character here only)

rem // Walk through the text file line by line:
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%FILE%") do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid loss of `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Double each `"` intermittently:
    set "LINE=!LINE:"=""!^" & rem "
    rem /* Enclose the entire line string within `""` and replace
    rem    each delimiter by `"` + SPACE + `"`; this results in a
    rem    SPACE-delimited list with each item enclosed within `""`: */
    set "LINE="!LINE:%DELIM%=" "!""
    rem /* Iterate through the built list using a standard `for` loop;
    rem    this works only in case no `*` or `?` occur in the string,
    rem    because `for` would consider them as global wildcards and
    rem    access the file system and through file-not-found errors: */
    for %%I in (!LINE!) do (
        endlocal
        rem /* Save item in variable (overwrite previous one, so
        rem    last item is retrieved), and remove surrounding `""`: */
        if not "%%~I"=="" set "LAST=%%~I"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    rem // Return last item per line, revert doubling `"`:
    if defined LAST echo(!LAST:""=^"!
    endlocal
)

rem // Return last item of last line, revert doubling `"`:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if defined LAST echo(!LAST:""=^"!
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: i tired your code , it works on simple cases , but in others i just received "=" again....

Comment: this one:  "08-09 15:39:38.236 D/MVSDKTutorialBasicOpenCloseFileLoop(12054): availableMemory = 636"  , try to add spaces randomly and test it.

Comment: It works for me with that line, even with additional spaces inserted; please provide a string that makes the script fail... What OS are you using?